# How to set a Dictionary as Value in POST API Call - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, parameters, nsdictionary, jsonmodel

I am making an API call in which the Parameters are as:

```
{
      name : XYZ,
      marks : { maths : 34 }
}
```

I am using [JSON model](http://www.jsonmodel.com/) for making API calls and handling the response.

Here is how I made params Dict:

```
NSMutableDictionary *paramsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *marksDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[marksDict setObject:"34" forKey:"maths"];

[paramsDict setObject:marksDict forKey:@"marks"];

[paramsDict setObject:@"XYZ" forKey:@"name"];
```

Here Goes my API CALL

```
APIManager *apimanager = [[APIManager alloc] init];
apimanager.delegate = self;

[apimanager getServerDataWithParam:paramsDict apiMethodType:kAPIMethodTypePOST andMapperClass:[StudentMarks class]];
```

My App Crashes giving me this Crash Log

```
Assertion failure in +[JSONHTTPClient urlEncode:], /Users/Documents/JSONHTTPClient.m:122
2016-08-12 12:46:16.653 ClassMgmt[30227:1338857] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request parameters can be only of NSString or NSNumber classes.
'{   maths = 34; }' is of class __NSDictionaryM.'
```

I don't want to convert my `NSDictionary` to `NSString` using:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@", aDictionary];
```

Is their any other way I can send `NSDictionary` as a value in `POST` Request as a parameter?

Comment: try this `[marksDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:34]
                   forKey:@"maths"];`

Answer (score 0):

Long-story-short; HTTP POST parameters can only be name/value pairs without hierarchy.

If you want to post JSON, on the other hand, that is part of the HTTP POST body, not the parameters.

Comment: so what should I do ?

Comment: @RahulMishra I've never used JSONModel, so I don't know how you use it to post JSON.  Perhaps just use one of the standard Apple libraries instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:kNilOptions error:nil]
NSString *paramsjsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```